# How to show nodes and ways on OpenStreetMap using Leaflet?

Tags: openstreetmap, react-leaflet, overpass-api

I was able to correctly query data from the OSM API.

Then, I've been able to show nodes on the map with the following codes:

```
for (let i = 0; i < data.elements.length; i++) {
   let pos;
   let marker;
   const e = data.elements[i];
   if (e.id in this._ids) {
       continue;
   }
                  
   this._ids[e.id] = true;
                  
   if (e.type === 'node') {
       pos = L.latLng(e.lat, e.lon);
   } 
   else{
       pos = L.latLng(e.center.lat, e.center.lon);
   }
   if (this.options.markerIcon) {
       marker = L.marker(pos, { icon: this.options.markerIcon });
   } 
   else {
       marker = L.circle(pos, 80, {
       stroke: false,
       fillColor: '#0000ff',
       fillOpacity: 0.9
       });
   } 
}
```

which gives me the following visual output:
[MyOutput-Image](https://i.stack.imgur.com/bKvjM.jpg)

How can I also show lines how it is done on [OverpassTurbo](https://overpass-turbo.eu/):
[OverpassTurbo-Image](https://i.stack.imgur.com/kDiR5.jpg)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

What does your OSM API query looks like? I assume it's an overpass query, in which case, you might have put an `out center` at the end, which returns the center of each way.

[Over pass out statement](https://wiki.openstreetmap.org/wiki/Overpass_API/Overpass_QL#out) :

> **center**: This adds only the centre of the above mentioned bounding box to ways and relations. Note: The center point is not guaranteed to lie inside the polygon (example).

Therefore, each way has a long/lat which is in the middle, which is what you plot as a marker using the `e.center.lat`

example of a way with `out center` :

```java
{
  "type": "way",
  "id": 2263973,
  "center": {
    "lat": 51.5070645,
    "lon": -0.1359499
  },
  "nodes": [
    9789823,
    9789817,
    3933850766,
    ...
  ],
  "tags": {...}
}
```

You could either go through each associated node, and look them up and get the lat and lon. Or use the `out geom` option which returns the coordinates or the nodes directly:

```js
{
  "type": "way",
  "id": 2263973,
  "bounds": {
    "minlat": 51.5064574,
    "minlon": -0.1363268,
    "maxlat": 51.5076716,
    "maxlon": -0.1355731
  },
  "nodes": [
    9789823,
    9789817,
    ...
  ],
  "geometry": [
    { "lat": 51.5064574, "lon": -0.1355731 },
    { "lat": 51.5069432, "lon": -0.1360143 },
    { "lat": 51.5072896, "lon": -0.1363027 },
    { "lat": 51.5073314, "lon": -0.1363255 },
    { "lat": 51.5073531, "lon": -0.1363268 },
    { "lat": 51.5073965, "lon": -0.1363228 },
    { "lat": 51.5074324, "lon": -0.1363027 },
    { "lat": 51.5074691, "lon": -0.1362638 },
    { "lat": 51.5076716, "lon": -0.1356893 }
  ],
  "tags": {...}
}
```

Notice how you also get the min and max values for latitude and in longitude in a `bounds` attribute. You can then go through the `geometry` array, extract all the lat and lon  in a latlngs array, and use:

`var polyline = L.polyline(latlngs, {color: 'blue'}).addTo(map);` to draw a line. See [Leaflet doc on polyline](https://leafletjs.com/reference.html#polyline)

And you can get this, for `[highway~motorway]`

[image]

Comment: Hi, i also have this problem can you help with this: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/75492962/how-to-get-nodes-in-openstreetmap-using-leaflet-strictly-contained-in-my-current